# Como imprimir o caractere ao invés da entidade HTML correspondente usando React?

Tags: javascript, html, string, react

Quero que o React faça aparecer na tela o emoji. Para isso eu sei o código do *HTML entity*. Quando passo para o componente o valor, funciona, mas quando passo por variável, não funciona.

```js
function H2({texto}) {
  return <h2>{texto}</h2>;
}

function App() {
  const abacaxi = "&#127821;";
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <H2 texto={abacaxi} />
      <H2 texto="&#127821;" />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Minha primeira vez aqui. ainda não conheço bem a ferramenta. valeu!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poderia até usar o [**`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), no entanto definir HTML a partir do código pode ser arriscado porque é fácil expor a **ataques de script entre sites (XSS)**, por isso o nome `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` e passar um objeto com uma chave `__html`, que é aparentemente complicada, isso para se lembrar de que é **perigoso**. Por exemplo:

```js
const Fragment = React.Fragment;

function H2({texto}){
  console.log(texto);
  return(<h2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: texto }}></h2>)
}

function App() {
  const abacaxi ="Constante &#127821;"
  return (

    <Fragment>
      <H2 texto={abacaxi}></H2>
      <H2 texto="Direto &#127821;"></H2>
    </Fragment>

  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  
  <App></App>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Também poderia usar `String.fromCodePoint`, mas só se for um código por vez, dessa forma você teria que fazer a leitura da string recebida um a um, obtendo a partir de `&` até `;` para cada entidade que deseja alterar e trocando a sequencia de caractere pelo valor correspondente do retorno de `String.fromCodePoint`, ou seja, só é mais eficiente usar isso se for para tratar algo bem simples, se for um texto grande, variado vai exigir escrever um longo script.

Para evitar o XSS e facilitar o caminho em muito, você usar [`DOMParser.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) assim conteúdos potencialmente perigosos não serão processados. Após o *parse* do HTML você pode remover todos atributos com prefixo `on`, tags `<script>` e diversos elementos desnecessários, seria melhor fazer uma lista de elementos permitidos ou pode simplesmente obter o conteúdo com `textContent`, que irá eliminar todo HTML e obter as entidades HTML já "processadas", podendo assim tratar uma strinng que possui quantidade de entidades variadas:

```js
const texto = `<strong>Teste</strong> &amp; &gt; <img src="teste.jpg" onload="alert('ataque XSS');" onerror="alert('ataque XSS');">

&#128512; &#128516; &#128525; &#128151;`;

const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(texto, "text/html");

console.log(parsed.body.textContent);
```

Dessa forma irá remover as tags HTML, mas irá manter as entidades HTML suportadas:

```js
const Fragment = React.Fragment;

function H2({texto}){
  texto = new DOMParser().parseFromString(texto, "text/html").body.textContent;
  return(<h2>{texto}</h2>)
}

function App() {
  const abacaxi ="<strong>Constante</strong> &#127821;"
  return (

    <Fragment>
      <H2 texto={abacaxi}></H2>
      <H2 texto="<strong>Direto</strong> &#127821;"></H2>
    </Fragment>

  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  
  <App></App>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Se você sempre tiver as [*HTML entities*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) no formato `&#...` onde `...` é um número decimal, você pode utilizar a função `String.fromCodePoint` e passar o número presente na entidade.

Claro que não funcionará com entidades nomeadas, como `&copy;` (referente ao caractere ”©”), mas se for `&#169;`, também equivalente a “©”, funcionaria. Isso porque o JavaScript não possui função nativa para associar o identificador “*copy*” ao caractere ”©”.

Exemplo:

```js
const entity = '&#127821;';
console.log(decimalHTMLEntityToString(entity));

function decimalHTMLEntityToString(entity) {
  const codePoint = parseInt(entity.substring(2, entity.length - 1), 10);
  if (Number.isNaN(codePoint)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid HTML entity.');
  }
  return String.fromCodePoint(codePoint);
}
```

E aí você usa essa função dentro do seu componente para analisar a *entity* recebida.

Claro que isso é bem mais eficiente que um DOM parser e mais seguro que utilizar o `__dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, mas não funciona para casos onde a *HTML entity* é qualificada pelo “nome” do caractere (e não pelo seu *code point*).

Como já vimos acima, isso só funcionaria para entidades HTML declaradas no padrão decimal ou hexadecimal (este último, todavia, não implementei nesta resposta, mas você já tem a ideia).